# Remove digit mark from float and convert to integer

Tags: java, jsp

Let's say that I have these variables:

```
float xx= 99.33f;
int yy=0;
```

I want to convert **xx** to **yy** by removing the digit marks, so that **yy** will be the number **9933**, preferably with a single line statement. How is this possible?

Comment: @ᴍaroun ᴍaroun I simplified the code, xx takes its value by a xx = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("price")); statement. Otherwise that would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this. its two line but, it might work.

```
float xx= (float) 99.33;
String yys=String.valueOf(xx).replace(".", "");
int yy=Integer.parseInt(yys);
```

Comment: That seems to work fine. I also combined it in one line like this: int yy = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(xx).replace(".", ""));

Answer (score 3):

Just the easiest way that comes up for me, but I assume that there could be easier ways to do that. But you can make it like a function.

```
String s = Float.toString(xx);
String[] temp=s.split("\\.");
yy=Integer.parseInt(temp[0]+temp[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
yy = (int) (xx * 100);
```